# Enable "Match dynamic range" in AVPlayer on tvOS

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos, hdr

I'm trying to make a simple streaming app in tvOS using Swift. I've basically just followed the example from Apple to get started, so the AVPlayer part of the code pretty much looks like this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos

All SDR streams seems to work just fine, but it's not working with HDR streams. It attempts to load, but then nothing happens.

My tvOS settings is set to SDR with "match dynamic range". If I force my AppleTV to always output HDR, then the HDR stream works just fine, so it seems to be something wrong with the dynamic switching.

On other apps, the "match dynamic range" seems to work just fine, and the Apple TV automatically switches to HDR when the stream has HDR.

So basically my question is if someone knows if I need to put something in the code to enable this correctly?

I've found that there is an HDRMode flag in AVPlayer, I haven't been able to find out how to use it.

Thanks!